# Delete all .jpg files that do not have a corresponding .xml file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataset

I am dealing with a dataset that has some files ".jpg" without its corresponding labels ".xml" in a folder, I want to delete or move all the ".jpg" files that do not have a corresponding label ".xml".
I have searched similar questions on here but I am failing to do so.
Here is a an image of what the folder looks like
[Folder with the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nTtN.png)

There are images with their labels as .xml files, I only want to get rid of .jpg that do not have the corresponding .xml label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

files = os.listdir(“directorylocation”)
for i in range(len(files)):
    if files[i].split(“.”)[0] + “.xml” not in files:
        #remove this file
```

This should list all files in a directory and do whatever you want with it if it does not have a matching .xml file

Comment: Thank you for the respone.
I tried to add "os.remove(files[i])" ,  but I ended up with an error saying

"FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '100023029811910s.jpg'"
While this image is present in the directory upon searching.

Comment: is your python script located in the same directory as your images?

Comment: Yes that was the problem, it clicked me right after I commented. Thanks again!

Comment: If not you have to give the remove function the exact location of the file.

Answer (score 0):

this code will delete all .jpg files that do not have a corresponding .xml file and all .xml files that do not have a corresponding .jpg file

```
  import os

files = os.listdir("training")
for i in files:
    for j in os.listdir("training/"+i):
        if (j.split(".")[0] + ".xml" not in os.listdir("training/"+i)) or (j.split(".")[0] + ".jpg" not in os.listdir("training/"+i)) :
        
            print(j)
            os.remove("training/"+i+"/"+j)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30844785)